# I write a function to find the prime number , but it's not working because I'm not able to break the loop

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop, numbers, break

```js
function isPrime(n) {

    if (n == 1 ) {
        return (`${n} is niether a prime number nor composite number`)
    }
    else if( n < 1){
        return (`${n} is not a prime number`)
    }
    else{
        for (let i = 2;  i < n; i++) {
            if( n % 2 == 0){
                return result = `${n} is not a prime number`
                break;
            }
            else{
                return result = `${n} is a prime number`
            }
        }
    }
}

console.log(isPrime(15))
```

I write a function to find the prime number , but it's not working because I'm not able to break the loop

Comment: The primary issue is, that `return` ends the function. There are a lot of other problems though.

Comment: `i%2==0` should be `i%n==0` - you are trying to see whether any number less than n is exactly divisible into n, not whether n is exactly divisible by 2 (which would not change ever, regardless of the value of i).

Comment: Hi, looks like, main problem is in your logic, not in code. Negative numbers also can be prime numbers. Also you need to check other dividers(3,5,7,....), not only 2...

Comment: a) `if( n % 2 == 0)` doesn't change per iteration, nor is it enough to indicate a prime. b) `result` is undeclared, nor does assigning immediately on return make sense. c) as mentioned above, `if ... return else return` always terminates the function, on the first iteration. d) style-wise (non-semantic problems), you should add semicolons, and don't need brackets around the top two template strings, especially when it's inconsistent, and you don't always place them.

Comment: `break` is *never* needed after `return` so the whole premise of your title is incorrect

Answer (score 0):

Although answer by Dave addresses the question I would suggest this stack overflow answer as an better alternative.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/38643868/10738743

Answer (score -1):

There are two glitches preventing your function working as intended.

1. the loop which tests for primeness is repeating `n%2` on each iteration, which will evaluate the same, regardless of the value of `i` in the loop. Instead, you should be testing to see whether `n%i` is true.
2. With that fixed, the final `return` (which only happens if all non-prime conditions have been rejected with earlier `return`s) should be outside of any block as it becomes the default return value.

your code functions fine with the minor changes suggested above incorporated:

```js
function isPrime(n) {
if (n == 1 ) {
    return (`${n} is niether a prime number nor composite number`);
}
else if( n < 1){
    return (`${n} is not a prime number`)
}
else {
    for (let i = 2;  i < n; i++) {
        if( n % i == 0){
            return result = `${n} is not a prime number`
            // break; // (return breaks anyway)
        } // end if       
    }// end for i;
    
    } // end else
    
    return result = `${n} is a prime number`; // default after no earlier rejection

}

console.log(isPrime(15));
```

Comment: Dave Pritlove, your code worked really well.